# What's wrong with my assertEquals?

Tags: java, junit

Still getting the red bar. What's wrong with the AssertEquals?

```
public void testFindEmployeeByID() {
    StubEmployeeRepositoryImpl result = new StubEmployeeRepositoryImpl(dataSource);
    List<Employee> emp = result.findEmployeesByName("John", "X");
    assertEquals("John"+"X", result.findEmployeesByName("John", "X"));
}
```

Comment: And what does that Red Bar says??

Answer (score 4):

Probably assertEquals doesn't know how to compare `List` and `String`...

Comment: Should i convert List to String? is that possible?

Comment: @FrustGoogleNow An intelligent idea might be getting the `Employee` from the list (if it supposed to be 1 employee) and convert the `Employee` to `String`. If the employee has two attributes like `firstName` and `surname`, you can make a `toString()` method returning this two attributes.

Comment: The method toString() in the type Object is not applicable for the arguments (List<Employee>)

Comment: @FrustGoogleNow Uff, `result.findEmployeesByName("John", "X").get(0).toString();`